# IllegalArgumentException: No view found when returning from other activity

Tags: android

This is setContentView()

```
setContentView(R.layout.game_activity); // "mainactivity" layout
```

This is in game_activity layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/containerFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    ...
```

This is in R.java

```
public static final class id {

    public static final int containerFrame=0x7f0a0004;
    public static final int gridFragment=0x7f0a0005;
    ...
```

Still getting:

```
09-09 14:55:12.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1972): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
No view found for id 0x7f0a0004 for fragment BlancFragment{41048548 #2 id=0x7f0a0004}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try to clean your project / restart your IDE ?

Comment: Did you add the activity to the manifest?

Comment: Show fragment transaction code where you replace or add `BlancFragment`. It seems that activity can't find id for that fragment.

Comment: This was completely my foult.  There is an othter activity in the application that starts the same fragment; there it went wrong. Thanks anyway.